# Fail to show PRIMEN org chart whose data was sent from back end

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, primeng

I want to show user's all related departments, and I will search all the department by the user name, so the back end is like below:

```
        [HttpGet("UserDepartment/{userName}")]
        public async Task<ActionResult<DepartmentDto>> GetUserDepartment(string userName)
        {
            var user = _context.Users.FirstOrDefault(u=>u.UserName==userName);
            if (user == null){ return NotFound();}
            var department = await _context.Departments.FindAsync(user.DepartmentId);
            if (department == null) { return NotFound(); }
            var dto= GetDepartmentTree(_mapper.Map<DepartmentDto>(department));
            return dto;
        }
        private DepartmentDto GetDepartmentTree(DepartmentDto rootDpt)
        {
            var subDpts = _context.Departments.Where(d => d.UpperDepartmentId == rootDpt.Id);
            var subDtos = _mapper.Map<DepartmentDto[]>(subDpts);
            if (subDpts != null)
            {
                rootDpt.Children = new List<DepartmentDto>();
                foreach (var subDto in subDtos)
                {
                    rootDpt.Children.Add(GetDepartmentTree(subDto));
                }   
            }
            return rootDpt;
        }
```

The dto got all children departments and send it to front endis:

```
    public class DepartmentDto
    {
        public long Id { get; set; }
        public string Code { get; set; }
        public string Label { get; set; }
        public List<DepartmentDto> Children { get; set; }
    }
```

In front end I'm using a service to get the dto:

```
  getUserDepartment(userName:string):Observable<department>{
    return this.httpClient.get<department>(`${environment.apiUrl}/Department/UserDepartment/${userName}`);
  }
```

And the component is like below:

```
  nodes:TreeNode[]=[];

  ngOnInit(): void {
    var dpt:department[];
    var user=this.authService.userValue;
    this.departmentService.getUserDepartment(user!.email).subscribe(
      data=>this.nodes=<TreeNode[]>JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data))
    );
  }

export interface department{
    id:number;
    name:string;
    code:string;
    children:department[];
}
```

The html is like:

```
<p-organizationChart [value]="nodes"></p-organizationChart>
```

By debugging I checked the back end works and the front end has already received data, but nothing showed on screen, it was all blank.

Comment: In order to get better help, you should show your HTML code, how you try to show this data.

Comment: Thank you for your sugguestion, I added the HTML.

Answer (score 0):

This solution is perfect for myself that we should add the root node manually to nodes in component like below:

```
  ngOnInit(): void {
     var user=this.authService.userValue;
    this.departmentService.getUserDepartment(user!.email).subscribe(
      data=>{
        this.nodes=[
          {
            label:data.label,
            children:data.children
          }
        ]
      }
    );  
  }
```

And the all levels of children would be automatically added as nodes.
Hope it is useful for anyone.